# Specifying a whole link line for SCons

Tags: linker, fortran, gfortran, scons, intel-mkl

How can I let `SCons` use the linker arguments, options, and flags in the order I want?

More specifically, I'm trying to build a program from Fortran source codes and Intel Math Kernel Library using GNU gfortran compiler on Linux. From Intel's link line advisor, I know that I should append the following segment to my linker command:

```
${F95ROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

where I also know `$F95ROOT` and `$MKLROOT` for my environment. In fact, if I do like

```
gfortran -o prog  file1.o file2.o  ${F95ROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

I can generate the executable file `prog`. However, if I try to let SCons do the same thing by writing a `SConstruct` file as

```
mklroot='/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl'
f95root='/home/norio/opt/intel/mkl2017_interfaces_gfortran484'

env['LIBS']=[f95root+'/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a', 
         'mkl_gf_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread', 'm', 'dl']
env['LIBPATH']=[mklroot+'/lib/intel64']
env['LINKFLAGS'] = ['-Wl,--no-as-needed']
```

then the SCons executes the following command:

```
gfortran -o prog -Wl,--no-as-needed file1.o file2.o -L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 -l/home/norio/opt/intel/mkl2017_interfaces_gfortran484/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64 -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

This results in the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/norio/opt/intel/mkl2017_interfaces_gfortran484/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64
```

It looks that SCons regarded the static library `f95root+'/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a'` specified in `env['LIBS']` as a shared library, and the linker failed to find such a shared library.
It may be enough if I know how to specify a static library for the build in this particular case. If you could tell me how to do so, I would also be very glad.
Nevertheless, I think sometimes the order of linker options, flags, and arguments may be important, and I'm interested in if there is any control over the order of them when SCons is used.

---

**Edit** on Wed Mar 22 00:53:34 IST 2017

I found that I can specify the static library by adding it to `source` argument of `Program()` command together with other source files, instead of listing it in env['LIBS']. So, something like the following can build the executable.

```
mklroot='/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl'
f95root='/home/norio/opt/intel/mkl2017_interfaces_gfortran484'
stat_lib_list=[f95root+'/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a']

env['LIBS']=['mkl_gf_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread', 'm', 'dl']
env['LIBPATH']=[mklroot+'/lib/intel64']
env['LINKFLAGS'] = ['-Wl,--no-as-needed']

..

env.Program(target='prog', source=['file1.f90','file2.f90']+stat_lib_list)
```

I still don't know how I can have a complete control of the whole linker line, or if SCons is really so smart to be able to figure out the order of options, flags, and arguments always successfully.

Comment: I think it is really worth having tag [tag:fortran] there. Decide whether instead of linux as I did it or instead some other, like gfortran. Scons does not care about individual compilers.

Comment: O.K. Thank you. That's fine. I wondered which of fortran or gfortran tag to put. Good to have both.

Comment: Why not use LIBPATH for the location of the library in question? (libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
mklroot='/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl'
f95root='/home/norio/opt/intel/mkl2017_interfaces_gfortran484'
env['LIBS']=['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 
     'mkl_gf_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread', 'm', 'dl']
env['LIBPATH']=[mklroot+'/lib/intel64',f95root ]
env['LINKFLAGS'] = ['-Wl,--no-as-needed']

..

env.Program(target='prog', source=['file1.f90','file2.f90'])
```

Furthermore I usually specify LIBS (and sometimes LIBPATH) with the builder so:

```
env.Program(target='prog', source=['file1.f90','file2.f90'],
            LIBS =['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_gf_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread', 'm', 'dl'],
            LIBPATH=[mklroot+'/lib/intel64',f95root ])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your method worked by modifying LIBPATH specification as `env['LIBPATH']=[f95root+'/lib/intel64', mklroot+'/lib/intel64']` (and without specifying LIBS and LIBPATH in the builder). The order of the elements of the `env['LIBPATH']` list was important because they appeared in this order as `-L` options on the command line, and there are files with the same name `libmkl_intel_thread.a` (but different contents) under both of these paths. I need to link to the one under `f95root+'/lib/intel64'`. So, I needed to put it first.

Comment: Great! If the above is the solution, please mark it as the answer?